# Bluescreen caused by ntoskrnl.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

My PC's screen goes entirely white/green/red etc. randomly. After rebooting the system I get bluescreen error dialog(dump file attached). Here is the screenshot from [bluescreenview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) an app for viewing bluescreen events and dump files.

[image]

I have done following things in attempt to resolve the issue:-

1. I first thought that it is due to corrupted system files. So I have re-installed the windows.
2. Then I had scanned the full system through [K7](https://apps.k7computing.com/Tools/K7avprm/setup-eng-avp.exe) antivirus software for any malware.
3. Then I had changed it's PSU.
4. I had also changed its CPU.
5. I had scanned it's system files by using "sfc /scannow" command and found no integrity violations.
6. I had run a memory diagnosis and found no issue.

The problem still persists, therefore any help will be appreciated.

---

[Mini Dump File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QOmxhMolpj4Pe7ALozrlCsfBc39eBrYI)

Comment: Which MiniDump File ?  There were several, so please provide the name of the minidump.   Then, given all you have done above, try updating BIOS and Video Drivers.

Comment: Test your memory using Memtest, run the extended tests>>>>>>>https://www.memtest.org/

Comment: @John The exact minidump file is 020420-15687-01.dmp . I had already updated Video Driver with the latest version and but I have not found the updated version of American Megatrends bios anywhere. Although I had tried some free auto bios update software but of no use.

Comment: I used Nirsoft Blue Screen View:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x124---whea-uncorrectable-error  .  This says there is still a hardware error. Find and run the Manufacturer's hardware test application

Comment: @John It is an generic motherboard so I think it's test application is hard to find.

Comment: The thing is that with all you did, it may be the motherboard that needs replacing. Tag says Windows 7, so it may be time for a new Windows 10 computer.

Comment: @John Ya, I will consider it replacing. Thanks for the help.